# JSON values 1 or 0 - int or boolean

Tags: json, integer, boolean

Does JSON treat these all the same? Or are they a mix of Integers and booleans?

```
var data =
{
    "zero" : 0,
    "one" : 1,
    "false" : 0,
    "true" : 1,
    "0" : false,
    "1" : true
}
```

Comment: You mean the values? Well, there is the Number type, and there is also the Boolean type. Therefore, those values are not the same.

Comment: BTW, `true` and `false` are reserved words, so you won't be able to use dot-notation to retrieve the property values. For instance, `data.zero` returns `0`, but `data.false` throws a parse error (in some browsers) (`data['false']` would work (= return `0`)).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

JSON is a format for transferring data.
It has no notion of equality.

JSON *parsers* treat booleans and numbers as distinct types.

Comment: This answer could have been more clearly explained, in this way:  *"Phil, you mention JSON, which is a format; what you mean to ask about are JSON parsers. In fact, JSON parsers...blah blah."*  Folks who are Top Explainers always trade away humour, mild sarcasm, witty inverted directness, surprising opening leads, and indeed any sort of stylistic gambit, whatsoever .. for absolute, total, explanatory power.  S., I direct a young man like you to the writings of Winston Churchill - you'd enjoy *My early life*, which is an exemplar of master language.  Cheers

Comment: What a pointless answer – and it's even wrong because there's actually an official [JSON specification](http://www.json.org) which shows that `true` and `false` literal values distinct from numbers. Any parser which failed to make that distinction is not a JSON parser.

Comment: If one does not like the fact that the exchange between the OP and the answer provider was mutually acceptable .. as evidenced by the green check mark, then please lead by example, not by rant.

Comment: Does not answer the question

Comment: @Eric: That's because the question has no answer / makes no sense.

Answer (score 90):

The values `true` and `false` are actual boolean values, the rest are integers. See http://json.org/ for more.

Comment: The link to json.org is useful here. I came to this question looking to see if JSON uses quotes around the values true and false.

Comment: In order to help those who find this post looking for the same info, the answer is "no". There are no quotes around the values `true` and `false` in JSON.

Answer (score 29):

I prefer using 0/1 instead of true/false, because 0/1 consume only 1 byte while true/false consume 4/5 bytes.

Comment: You may prefer it but using 0/1 doesn't always work. When using JWT for example.

Comment: Couldn't give you an exact figure, but since you should be compressing your JSON to the client anyway, then I don't think that the bytes you save uncompressed by using 0/1 are worth not following the standard. GZip/Brotli compression will likely substitute 'true' and 'false' for a shorter lookup value into a table. The more often 'true' or 'false' appear in your data, the greater the saving. Really not worth worrying about. Write code / generate JSON that follows standards. When you've gone someone else will appreciate it. Otherwise they'll hate you.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned, at JSON level, 0 and false are not the same; data types are number versus boolean.
But JSON processing libraries can choose to do conversions; especially on languages/platforms that do not have native boolean type, for example. In that case, another representation may be used (empty string or 0 for false).

Further, it is also possible that processing libraries can coerce types: such that if a boolean value is expected, certain number/string values (or JSON 'null' token) can be accepted instead.
This is fairly common, due to differences on data type choices on different languages.